# Center inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to center an ImageView and TextView inside a RelativeLayout.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout    
        android:id="@+id/teamNameLayout"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"          
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/teamPosition"          
    >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/teamIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/logo1"
            android:layout_width="20dip"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                    
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="16sp" 
             />
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/teamName"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"                        
       android:textColor="#000000"  
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="16sp"      
       android:text="blabla" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried the "center_horizontal" with no success.
I need the ImageView will be to the right of the TextView.

Comment: Do you want ImageView and TextView combined to the center of the view?

Comment: Yes. and I also need a padding for the textview from the imageview.

Comment: A RelativeLayout doesn't have an orientation btw

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've tried the "center_horizontal" with no success. I need the
>   ImageView will be to the right of the TextView.

=> Try `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for your TextView, and use `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/teamName` in your ImageView.

Comment: Thanks, that works. And if I also need padding for the textview from the imageview ?